# regla ngnix proxy_pass y try_files en la raiz

Tags: nginx

Hola necesito hacer un redireccionamiento desde la raiz con un proxy_pass pero tambien tengo reglas y no me esta funcionando, aca el codigo:

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $index_by_browser =404;
  }
```

y necesito hacer un proxy_pass hacia otra direccion desde la raiz, aca el codigo que hice:

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $index_by_browser =404 @proxy;
  }
  location @proxy {
     proxy_pass  http://172.17.0.1:4000/nueva-ruta; 
  }
```

pero no me logra funcionar, me arroja error 404 siempre, alguna idea??? gracias...

Comment: quita el `=404`, sino ¿Cómo esperas que llegue a @proxy?